# Could I cross-post a question on biology SE like this :

Tags: discussion

Could I cross-post a question on biology SE like this :

https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4456/while-someones-ears-pops-with-pressure-can-he-she-hear-other-sound-at-the-same

Because i might be more likely to get an answer to this on the biology SE .

(it's ok to migrate this question to meta.biology for i don't have enough reputation. )

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, cross posting is [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/203101) on the whole SE network so no, don't cross post it. That said, your question seems to be perfectly on topic here and would be welcome (on the main site, not the meta, meta is for discussing the site not for asking biological questions).

The normal method for moving questions around the network is either to delete one and ask again on another site or to flag the question for moderator attention and ask them to migrate it for you.